# Openstack virtualbox configuration

Tags: virtualbox, openstack

I am installing openstack in centos which in turn runs inside virtualbox installed in Ubuntu
Ubuntu > Virtualbox > CentOS> Openstack Rocky

I have 2 adapters for virtualbox centos image:

1. NAT
2. Bridge Adapter(not paravirtualized)

Steps I followed:

1. Assigned static IP to bridged adapter
2. NAT runs on DHCP
3. Made bridged interface as OVS port
4. Made br-ex as OVS Bridge
5. Used packstack to install openstack rocky
6. Made an external network and attached an instance directly to it. The instance gets the IP in the same range as Centos or Ubuntu.

I am able to ping

- instance <=> centos <=> ubuntu <=> instance

But I am not able to ping outside.

Please suggest what I could be doing wrong/missing. 
Thanks for helping :)